# Error 404: Hosting Laravel app on webhost

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404

I have been trying to put my Laravel app on a webhost. Had some problems doing so, in the end I managed to get it working. CSS loads, the components load, everything works like it should, except the functionality of the controllers. It is impossible for me to login/register.

I have been following this tutorial all the way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4

The steps I've taken to get it to work which is also discussed in the video are the following:

- Zipping the whole Laravel project and uploading it on the FTP under the subdomain, so the folder would be project.site_url.com->laravel_project_directory.
- Unzipping the zip file via the filemanager of cpanel

The extracted files are the following:
[files in project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0fyZ.png)

- I have gotten everything out of the 'public' folder and put them in the subdomain directory so that the public folder would dissapear and I would be able to use the link of the site without having the put /public behind it to display the website.
- Change 'index.php' into:

```html
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';
```

- Changed 'server.php' into:

```html
'public' => __DIR__.'/..',
```

- Edit the .htaccess file to:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

After doing all this, I'm able to see the CSS being loaded but I'm not able to login/register. Doing so gives me the following error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPcKN.png)

```html
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php",
    "line": 43,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
            "line": 162,
            "function": "handleMatchedRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 635,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 624,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 613,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 165,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php",
            "line": 36,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 140,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 109,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/n0load1q/docuSite.0loading.com/public/index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

The error I get in the console: [Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUf32.png)

Answer (score 0):

if in your project .env file not exist add & config that.

Comment: I have updated my post with the steps I've taken to get it to work.